# Remove duplicate url in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\91901\PycharmProjects\kk\drivers\chromedriver.exe')

# page_no = input('Enter Page Number : ')
page_no = '2'
blog_page = driver.get('https://xmonks.com/blog/page/' + page_no + '/')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1500)")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2000)")
time.sleep(2)
soup = Bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(3)
link = soup.find('div', {'class': 'exp-grid-wrap'})
lnk = link.find_all('a')
for links in lnk:
        ll = links.get('href')
        print(ll)
```

i am fetching blog urls from this website , but i am getting some duplicate urls , please help how can i remove duplicate urls , thanks in advance

Comment: set would get you all unique urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer, I haven't been using Python for some time now.

You're getting all from the link variable.

You can de-dup list in your loop. Introduce another list and add only if item is not already present.

```
unique_url = list()
for links in lnk:
    ll = links.get('href')
    if ll not in unique_url:
        unique_url.append(ll)
        print(ll)
```

Comment: Thanks it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the right element to get what you need. I used the `a tag` which had the thumbnail enclosed in it and it worked.

This will give you the output:

```
soup = Bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
sleep(3)

a_tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'exp-post-thumb-inner'})

links = [i['href'] for i in a_tags]
for i in links:
    print(i)

# output

https://xmonks.com/mindfulness-meditation-coaching/
https://xmonks.com/the-healing-aspects-of-mindfulness-coaching/
https://xmonks.com/techniques-to-be-mindful-a-word-by-and-for-the-coaches/
https://xmonks.com/understanding-mindfulness-coaching/
https://xmonks.com/neuroscience-of-emotions-and-values/
https://xmonks.com/neuroscience-of-beliefs/
https://xmonks.com/coaching-skills-for-leaders/
https://xmonks.com/neuroscience-of-goals/
https://xmonks.com/simplifying-coaching-coaching-matters/
https://xmonks.com/solution-focused-coaching/
```